# Allocating a struct having function pointers as fields

Tags: c, linux, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was trying to allocate a struct in C having function pointers as fields, however, valgrind throws the error "Invalid write of size 8" for the following code. However, when `int n=1` is changed to `int n=10`, the code does not produce errors (when allocating way more than necessary memory does not produce an error).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list {
    int (*one)(int,int);
    int (*two)(int,int);
};

int one0(int x,int y){return x+y;}
int two0(int x,int y){return x-y;}

void assignFunctions(struct list * l){
    l->one = one0;
    l->two = two0;
}

int main(){
    int n = 1;
    struct list * l = calloc(n, sizeof(struct list *));
    assignFunctions(l);
    free(l);
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the issue here? Compiled with:
`gcc -O0 -g a.c && valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./a.out`
Keep in mind that this is not a real code, it is a simplification of a code I had to deal with. Moreover, the code of `assignFunction(struct list *l)` and `struct list {}` cannot be changed. So, my real question is how to allocate this struct?

Comment: You want to allocate enough space for a `struct list`, but you allocate only enough space for a pointer to one.  The details of the structure members are of little import here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have allocated memory for a `struct list *`. But what really wanted is to allocate memory for a `struct list`. That's what Valgrind complains about. Since you haven't allocated suffciently and assigning to the member pointers, this results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

```
struct list *l = calloc(n, sizeof(struct list));
```

Or, better:

```
struct list *l = calloc(n, sizeof *l);
```

should fix your problem.